# generated webfonts from fontsquirrel site, how to change the directory?

Tags: css, directory, font-face, webfonts

Generated several webfont kits from FontSquirrel's font generator, put them into css file, they work but only if the files are in the same directory with css file.

How do I make them work while specifying a different directory??

Present code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRoman';
    src: url('chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('chunkfive-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfont374IVrsF') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I'd like all the files to live in `/assets/webfonts`.

I tried `/assets/webfonts` and `../assets/webfonts` ...these do not work...

Thank you, Tom

Answer (score 2):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url):

> Partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document

So, where are the fonts located relative to your css?

`/assets/webfonts/` says to start looking in the root folder.

`../assets/webfonts/` looks for the path starting up one directory level

If your `assets` folder is a subdirectory in the folder where your css is, try `assets/webfonts/`

Comment: stylesheet is in /assets/css, fonts are in /assets/webfonts, so it should be ../webfonts/?? I will try that, I already tried the other two ideas which did not work...Thank you, Tom

Comment: I tried url('webfonts/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), to give one example, and url('/webfonts/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), neither one worked.

note: woff is not the only webfont I use, this is just an example url text.

/ is root
/assets contains /css and /webfonts
browsers will only display webfonts if the url is specified as
url('chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), meaning the fonts are in the same folder as the calling css file.

SO I guess I must leave the webfonts in the css directory until somewhere I find a better solution.

Thank you, Tom